# Image doesn't toggle back to original state after second click

Tags: jquery, html, image, liquid

When an image is clicked I want it to be replaced with another image. Once the newly replaced image is clicked I want it to change back to the original image. Right now the image is replaced but doesn't change back. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**HTML**

```
<img src="{{ 'onesize-triangle.png' | asset_url }}" class="size-btn onesize-btn" data-quantity="{{ variant.available }}" data-id="{{ variant.id }}" id="imgClickAndChange" data-size="{{ variant.title }}" onclick="changeImage()"/>
```

**jQuery**

```
function changeImage() {

      if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "{{ 'onesize-triangle.png' | asset_url }}") 
      {
          document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "{{ 'onesize-triangle_on.png' | asset_url }}";
      }
      else 
      {
          document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src = "{{ 'onesize-triangle.png' | asset_url }}";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

== missing in if statement, do it as below:

```
  if (document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange").src == "{{ 'onesize-triangle.png' | asset_url }}")
```

plus in your else part first clear  previous src and then add new src  like below:

Comment: That doesn't toggle the second image for me

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo

http://jsfiddle.net/AmqcY/

**JS CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //use event delegation
  $(document).on('click','#imageid',function(){

    var $this= $(this);
    $('#toggle').toggle('slide',function(){
      //swap src of the image on toggle is completed
      var imgsrc = $this.attr('src');
      $this.attr('src',$this.data('othersource'));
      $this.data('othersource',imgsrc);
   });
  });
});
```